# Failing to export to CSV in Python, multiple formats

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas, jupyter

I am trying to export to CSV files from a Jupyter notebook. Even when I test examples copy-pasted from the documentation (see below), I get a "'str' object is not callable" error message. I have fiddled endlessly with the parameters. The same thing happens with a Pandas dataframe and I try to use to_csv.

Basically:

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
```

yields

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-169-cc34b7e892ee> in <module>()
  1 import csv
  2 with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
----> 3     spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I'm new to coding, so I don't really know how to troubleshoot past this point...can anyone help?

Comment: What's in eggs.csv?

Comment: Why do I get the feeling that the complete code isn't being shown?

Comment: When I run this example locally, it works both in plain terminal and in the jupyter notebook. The reason for your error is that you may have a non-standard csv module installed, or that you ran some other code after importing "csv" (for example something like `csv.writer = "egg.csv"`). I'd suggest trying to open a new Jupyter notebook and run just those 3 lines fresh.

Comment: The complete code? Yeah, I didn't paste my entire Jupyter notebook...Either way, opening a new notebook solved everything. I know, embarrassing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are seeing can only be explained if `csv.writer` is a string. This recreates your error:

```
In [1]: import csv

In [2]: csv.writer = 'test'   # <- cause error

In [3]: %paste
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)

## -- End pasted text --
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-cc34b7e892ee> in <module>()
      1 import csv
      2 with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
----> 3     spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I'm guessing you are either working in an environment like Spyder which by default keeps a single session alive for code to run in, or you are experimenting in a REPL like IPython or a Jupyter notebook. At some point you mistakenly assigned a new value to  `csv.writer`. The problem will go away if you reset your environment, since there is nothing wrong with your code.

To reset, for IPython or Spyder just exit and start again. For Jupyter notebook select "Kernel|Restart" from the menu.

Comment: Indeed, restarting the kernel fixed it all. I feel pretty silly for not having tried that, so I truly appreciate the background explanation and lack of snark :)